# Llamar una función de un archivo archivo Javascript propio con funciones desde un componente

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, component

Como puedo llamar una función javascript de un archivo propio con funciones desde un componente de angular.

Yo cargo desde el ***index.html*** el archivo ***jcc.js*** con mis funciones inclusives esta **`JFecha()`**

Me arroja el siguiente **error**:

> ERROR in src/app/components/footer/footer.component.ts(15,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JFecha'.

**Mí código**:

```
// tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
  selector: "app-footer",
  // tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
  templateUrl: "./footer.component.html",
  // tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
  styleUrls: ["./footer.component.css"]
})
export class FooterComponent {
  anio: string;
  constructor() {
    this.anio = JFecha();
  }
}
```

**El HTML**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>julio.corbaz@gmail.com</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="assets/js/jcc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>
```

> Nota: JFecha es una funcion mia propia de un archivo js que se encuentra en **`assets/js/jcc.js`**

Comment: Explicate mejor para entenderte,de donde quieres llamar la funcion? y para que?

Comment: Hola Julio te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta, además de pegar tu código como texto en lugar de una imagen, así es más fácil y tienes más posibilidades que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias es mi primera pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esta manera. Primero deberás añadir la palabra export delante de la función que quieres utilizar fuera del archivo, por ejemplo:

```
 export function JFecha() { 
    console.log("Hoy es Miércoles"); 
 }
```

Una vez hecho esto debes ir al componente e importar ese archivo de la siguiente manera:

```
 import * as archivo from '../assets/js/jcc.js';
```

Finalmente mediante el objeto archivo podrás acceder a todas las funciones o variables que tengas exportadas desde el archivo desde dentro de los componentes:

```
archivo.JFecha();
```

Answer (score 3):

### Primera opción

Sabiendo que todo código Javascript válido es código Typescript válido (porque Typescript es un superconjunto de Javascript), intentaría incluir ese código como un fichero `.ts` más:

- renombras el fichero a jcc.ts y lo colocas dentro de `src/app/utils` (por ejemplo).
- exportas las funciones de dicho fichero:

  ```
  export function JFecha () {...}
  ```
- importas dicho fichero del mismo modo que cualquier otro fichero ts:

  ```
  import {JFecha} from '../utils/jcc';
  ```

### Segunda opción

Otra solución sería decirle al compilador de Typescript que asuma que esa función existe de manera global, creando un fichero de declaración de tipos:

- creas un fichero `/src/@types/jcc.d.ts`
- declaras ahí la existencia de las funciones, extendiendo la interfaz Window:

  ```
  interface Window {
    JFecha: () => any;
  }
  ```
- Typescript debería escanear todos los ficheros .d.ts y añadir estas declaraciones.
- Cargas el fichero JS en index.html, añadiéndolo como un *asset* para asegurarte de que sea incluido en el *build*.

Comment: export function JFecha () {...} que se pone en los 3 puntos {...}

Comment: Se pone el fragmento de código que quieras ejecutar